# First time loading a window in new scene, it opens two

Tags: python, import, reload, maya

I have this code.....

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '...')

import rotTool
reload(rotTool)
rotTool()
```

First time loading it into maya I get two windows. I realize it's because of the reload there, but without it, it won't load if you closed the window and need to reopen (while in the same session). How best should I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: While it's _usually_ safe, the auto-reload is something you only want to use while you're developing. It's forcing the module to rebuild itself which can have unpredictable side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say inside rotTool.py it looks something like this:

```
from PySide import QtGui

class RotTool(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(RotTool, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(400, 400)

    def run(self):
        self.show()
```

It's a class that inherits from a `QWidget`, and when you call the run function, it opens up a window and shows it. Maybe you're not using `PySide` but the same idea should apply.

In Maya, if I need to open this window I execute:

```
import rotTool # Import module

myWin = rotTool.RotTool() # Create an instance of the class
myWin.run() # Call the instance's run method to open it up
```

If I close the window, I can just execute the last 2 lines again to create a new instance that opens the window. There could be a bit more to it than that, like making sure 2 windows can't be open at the same time, but this is how I would generally go about it.

I'm not sure what's in your module so it's hard to give specific advice to it. Instead of opening your window at the bottom of your script, you might just need to wrap it around a function, like my `run()` example, so that it doesn't automatically open on an `import` or `reload`. Hope that helps!